# Moving files while they are copied?

Tags: windows-7

I am copying about a terabyte worth of data composed of several thousand files. Windows estimates about 7 hours left, however, while it is copying, I moved a file to a different location. Windows has not come to that file yet.

Will it run into problems later as it tries to copy the file, or will it know that I moved it and still copy it? I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

It won't copy it, but will skip it. It will produce an error message. You could copy it back to prevent this from happening, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving it just copy it since it's not possible to move a file while it's being processed. You can always delete the original file from the source drive afterwards and this way you won't have to worry about any error prompts while everything is copying.